# Authenticate if user is loggedin and if session and db matches

Tags: php, database, codeigniter, session

I have this on my pages controller.

```
protected $auth = array();

function __construct(){
parent::__construct();
$this->auth['result'] = $this->is_logged_in();
}
```

and this is my core/base controller located at core folder.

```
public function is_logged_in(){
$session = $this->session->userdata();
if(isset($session['logged_in'])){
    return $session;
}else{ return FALSE; }
}
```

Is the above codes enough? or am i missing something to do a legitimate authentication?(my first time trying to attempt a user authentication)

Also, would it be okay, if for example.

I added a column '`isLoggedin`' on my accounts table.

```
int(1),NULL.
```

and whenever my login function is called and someone successfully logs in, i will also add a value to insert as '`isLoggedin`' to 1. `1=true, 2=false`.

So for example in my pages controller, since everytime it loads, it runs the `is_logged_in()` function in my base controller and would return the session data from there.

I would compare the returned session data from my base controller to the one in my accounts table with the '`isLoggedin`' col set to 1.

Also, quick question.

In my model, there is a query line: `$result = $this->db->insert('accounts',$data);`

if i return `$result`, does it return TRUE/FALSE based on the success or failure of the query?(if inserted = 1?)

i already did a `print_r($result);` but it showed a 1. I'm not sure if this 1 means TRUE just in int value.

Also, how do i declare a value boolean? so it would print as TRUE or FALSE.

I already tried, `boolean $result` but it would return as parse error.

Answer (score 1):

In codeigniter , In case of TRUE it returns 1 but in case of FALSE it returns nothing ,if you do print_r() for checking result result .But if you do var_dump() then it will show you bool(false)/bool(true) value. So if you have to check session is maintained or not according to your code , you can check like this:-

```
function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->auth['result'] = $this->is_logged_in();
        if(($this->auth['result']))
        {
           echo "session is set";/*Here your session is set*/ 
        }
        else
        {
            echo "session is not set";/*Here your session is not set*/
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

For your first question, for a very simple case, this is enough. But in a rather more complex project, you need to check more parameters (like validity time, password change, etc.).

As for your second one, although you did not specify in your code or description, but from your method specification, I believe the code is most probably based on CodeIgniter.

And you are right. According to the CodeIgniter documentation [here](https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/query_builder.html#class-reference), insert returns `TRUE on success, FALSE on failure`, and the return value should be in `bool` type.

```
insert([$table = ''[, $set = NULL[, $escape = NULL]]])

Parameters: 
    $table (string) – Table name
    $set (array) – An associative array of field/value pairs
    $escape (bool) – Whether to escape values and identifiers
Returns:    
    TRUE on success, FALSE on failure
Return type:    
    bool
```